# Matlab & Xcode 5 : "clang: link fails"

Tags: xcode, macos, matlab

I've tried to install the [nfft package](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/) on my MacBook Pro OS X 10.9, using Xcode 5. 
When I test the nfft package, I have to compile a .c file using the following command:

```
fftw3Path='/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/fftw-3.3.4/';
nfft3Path='/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/';
Ipath=[' -I' nfft3Path 'include ' ' -I' nfft3Path 'applications/fastsum ' '-I' fftw3Path 'api ' '-I' nfft3Path 'matlab ' ];
Lpath=['-L' nfft3Path ' ' '-L' nfft3Path 'applications/fastsum' ' ' '-L' fftw3Path 'api' ];
command=sprintf(['mex -v -Dchar16_t=uint16_t ' Lpath ' ' Ipath ' -lfftw3 -lnfft3 nfftmex.c']);
eval(command)
```

Here is the answer that I get:

`Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
    /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.8 clang -c -Dchar16_t=uint16_t  -DMX_COMPAT_32   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/include -I/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/applications/fastsum -I/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/fftw-3.3.4/api -I/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/matlab  -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -O2 -DNDEBUG /Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/matlab/nfft/nfftmex.c -o /var/folders/_0/63lwd1z17j94w_7wgkrw3x700000gn/T//mex_2747778005296_34460/nfftmex.o
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.8 clang -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" /var/folders/_0/63lwd1z17j94w_7wgkrw3x700000gn/T//mex_2747778005296_34460/nfftmex.o  -O -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"  -lfftw3  -lnfft3   -L/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/  -L/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/nfft-3.2.3/applications/fastsum  -L/Users/boyer/Documents/MATLAB/fftw-3.3.4/api   -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++ -o nfftmex.mexmaci64
    Error using mex
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_nfft_mex_get_int", referenced from:
    _mexFunction in nfftmex.o
    "_nfft_mex_install_mem_hooks", referenced from:
    _mexFunction in nfftmex.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Using MatlabR2011b, I have changed the mexopts.sh file as follows:

> ```
> ;;
>     maci64)
> #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         #PATCH: MacOSX10.9
>         CC='llvm-gcc'
>         CXX='llvm-g++'
>         SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/'
> ```

```
        MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
        ARCHS='x86_64'

        # StorageVersion: 1.0
        # CkeyName: GNU C
        # CkeyManufacturer: GNU
        # CkeyLanguage: C
        # CkeyVersion:
        CFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        #CFLAGS='-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE'
        CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -std=c99"
        CFLAGS="$CFLAGS  -fexceptions"
        CLIBS="$MLIBS"
        COPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
        CDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
        #
        CLIBS="$CLIBS -lstdc++"
        # C++keyName: GNU C++
        # C++keyManufacturer: GNU
        # C++keyLanguage: C++
        # C++keyVersion: 
        CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch $ARCHS -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
        CXXFLAGS='-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE'
        CXXLIBS="$MLIBS -lstdc++"
        CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG'
        CXXDEBUGFLAGS='-g'
```

I have also tried to change the libraries -lstdc++ by -std=libstdc++. Nothing solves the problem.

Then I used MatlabR2014a, and I have the same error (but in this version, we cannot modify the mexopts.sh, it seems to have been replaced by mex_C_maci64.xml).

I think that maybe I will install another c-compiler which is too bad since at least MatlabR2014a is supposed to be compatible with Xcode5.

If you have any suggestion, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hate banging my head against brick walls when trying to install software on OSX, so I use `homebrew` for ImageMagick, GNU coreutils, gawk, sed, ffmpeg, gnuplot, GNU parallel, REDIS, opencv, jhead, p7zip etc.

There seems to be a formula for `nfft`, so I suspect all you need to do is install `homebrew`, by going to [their website](http://brew.sh) and following the simple one-line instruction. Then you can `tap` into the science branch of the repository and install `nfft` like this:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install nfft
```

And you are finished! If there are any problems, run

```
brew doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help and useful suggestions. Now, it seems to work by applying the following command when installing the nfft package (before make and make install):

```
./configure --with-fftw3='/usr/local' --with-fftw3-libdir='/usr/local/lib' --with-fftw3-includedir='/usr/local/include' --with-matlab='/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app' --with-matlab-fftw3-libdir='/usr/local/lib'
```

Another comment: even if the version of OS X is 10.9, matlab selects 10.8sdk. To avoid this, you can edit the file mex_C_maci64.xml, and invert 2 lines of codes:

```
<dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk" />
                  <dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk" />
                  <dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.7.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.9.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.8.sdk" />
```

instead of

```
<dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk" />
                  <dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk" />
                  <dirExists name="$$/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.7.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.8.sdk" />
                  <cmdReturns name="find $$ -name MacOSX10.9.sdk" />
```

end

Hope it can help someone else. Thank you again for your answers.